# How can the challenge date of an application be extended?

Tags: patent-applications, challenge, date

The [challenge on Microsoft's patent US 20130063492](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/3566/8289) states:

> Availability for Challenge: Open Until at least Sept 14, 2013

How is the "available for challenge" date obtained?

What steps must we take to extend the challenge date of an application?

Comment: The window closes 6 months after the day of publication.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite, Considering that there's a huge flood of new patents everyday, I would find 6 months bordering on unfair. Is there any way that we can apply to extend the challenge date of a particular application?

Comment: Until the new AIA law went into effect there was no such thing as this widow to allow submissions that the examiner is required to consider. Having this at all was a very big break with the past thinking. There are other rules that allow you to send something in almost anytime but there is no requirement or expectation that the examiner will look at it. To get the time window extended can be done by legislation.